# SSHException Error with connecting to sFTP using Paramiko Lib - Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I am trying to connect to an sFTP and transfer files but getting an SSHException error.

I am using Python 3.4.3.7, 64bit

I am using paramiko library and SFTPClient protocol:

```
import paramiko

transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp.get(remote_path,local_path)
sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
'Unable to connect to %s: %s' % (hostname, reason))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Unable to connect to host: [WinError     10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I also tried to connect via SSHClient protocol and I got the same error. Code used is:

```
import os
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: can you connect from command line?

Comment: Nope I cannot connect

Comment: And what is the error? Post verbose log. Some exception does not make it more clear.